# Eclipse, where to change the current debug line background?

Tags: eclipse, colors

Can anyone point me to the preferences page that has the setting of the **DEBUG** current line background color? I have changed almost all the colours to dark ones and still get annoyed by this almost white current line indicator while debugging (note that the current line indication in editing mode is OK).

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Ok, now I found it myself (through major reverse engineering). It is in General\Editors\Text Editors\Annotations page. It's called "Debug Current Instruction Pointer"

Comment: GGGGGggggreat! I had to select the text to be able to read it! (I wasn't gonna change my whole color scheme for that damn debugger!) and couldn't find this configuration! thanks!

Comment: As lori mentioned in another comment, make sure to mark both  "General\Editors\Text Editors\Annotations\Debug Call Stack" and "General\Editors\Text Editors\Annotations\Debug Current Instruction Pointer" the the same color.

Comment: I just don't understand why color is so hard to change in eclipse.  I feel like its such a basic functionality of an ide.

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to define the text color for this scenario?  I'm well familiar with the syntax coloring options, I just don't see one that applies to the current line while debugging.  Now that I was able to define the background color of the currently debugged line, not all of my syntax is easy to see.  I'm looking to make it work like Visual Studio where my currently debugged line is yellow and the text shows in black, regardless of my defined syntax color settings which apply when I'm NOT debugging.

Comment: @GregLoehr ask a question on stackoverflow, someone will answer I am sure.

Answer (score 15):

On my version of Eclipse it is

> General\Editors\Text Editors\Annotations\Debug Call Stack"

Comment: I think this is a different one, it's showing you exactly the call stack (when you go up the stack, and are not in the current stack frame).

Answer (score 8):

Because Eclipse change stuff more than they change clothes

As of Eclipse for Java EE 2019-09 , took me 30 min just to find this stupid preferences

[image]

Than go to

[image]