# How to keep highlighting of the executed Java lines in Eclipse Debug Mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage

When i start Run Coverage in Eclipse, the executed (covered) lines are highlighted. How can i have this highlighting for Debug Mode? Maybe with an Eclipse plugin?

Our application is so big, it is sometimes impossible to debug through all the lines, and eventually database timeout occurs anyway, so we have to start debugging from beginning. I would like to have the chance **to see which lines were actually executed** (after the execution).

EDIT: I don't mean "current debugged line". I mean "debugged lineS".  I want that the executed lines keep the highlighting also after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse highlights the current debugged lines automatically, maybe you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211500/eclipse-where-to-change-the-current-debug-line-background)

Comment: I don't mean "current debugged line". I mean "current debugged lineS".  I want that the executed lines keep the highlighting also after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could print the debug information using ANSI control characters. You probably need to install a plugin to Eclipse in order this to work. You can try [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console#.VJGZ8Pl_sjw) for example.